SAML Response Validation Fails with "Invalid Document Signature" in Node.js
I'm working with SAML authentication using node-saml in my Node.js application. The SAML response status is success, but when I attempt to validate the response, I get the following error:
Error: Invalid document signature
Here is my current SAML configuration:
import { SamlConfig } from '@node-saml/node-saml';

export const samlConfig: SamlConfig = {
  entryPoint: process.env.SAML_ENTRY_POINT || 'https://idp.com/saml2',
  issuer: process.env.SAML_ISSUER || 'https://example.com',
  callbackUrl: process.env.SAML_CALLBACK_URL || 'https://example.com/auth/saml/callback',
  idpCert: process.env.SAML_CERT || `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (certificate)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`,
  signatureAlgorithm: 'sha1',
  disableRequestedAuthContext: true,
};


In my SAML callback handler, I'm using validatePostResponseAsync to validate the response:
async handleSamlCallback(req: any, res: any): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const { SAMLResponse } = req.body;
    
    if (!SAMLResponse) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'SAMLResponse is missing' });
    }

    const profile = await this.saml.validatePostResponseAsync({
      SAMLResponse,
    });

    console.log('profile', profile);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error validating SAML response:', e);
    res.status(401).send('Invalid SAML Response');
  }
}


What I have tried:

Ensured the IdP certificate matches the one provided.
Checked the SAML response structure by decoding it from base64, and it seems to be well-formed.
The SAMLResponse status was a success, but the validation still fails.

When I switch to passport-saml, everything works fine without modifying anything on the IdP side.
However, passport-saml is getting deprecated, so I need to resolve this using node-saml.

Check if the certificate you're using (idpCert) exactly matches the one provided by your Identity Provider (IdP). A mismatch in the certificate can cause the signature validation to fail. Verify that: The certificate is in the correct format (PEM).
No extra characters or spaces are present.
If your IdP is rotating certificates, ensure you’re using the current active one.


When I switch to passport-saml, everything works fine without modifying anything on the IdP side. However, passport-saml is getting deprecated, so I need to resolve this using node-saml.

Based on information at your question you are migrating away from https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-saml (which is deprecated and also known as passport-saml version < 4.0.0).
It is deprecated because passport-saml was splitted (starting from 4.0.0) to

@node-saml/node-saml ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/@node-saml/node-saml )
which contains core SAML 2.0 functionality which can be used to implement SAML 2.0 web SSO profile at SP side (whithout any dependencies to any specific web frameworks like Express or PassportJS)
@node-saml/passport-saml ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/@node-saml/passport-saml )
which uses internally @node-saml/node-saml package and provide SAML 2.0 PassportJS module. Almost all configuration parameters are passed through to internally used @node-saml/node-saml

so you are not forced to resolve this with @node-saml/node-saml because you could use @node-saml/passport-saml instead of passport-saml package.
Regardless of usage of @node-saml/node-saml or @node-saml/passport-saml your problem is caused by change which was made to 4.0.0 of @node-saml/node-saml (and to @node-saml/passport-saml due to how it uses former internally). Starting from version 4.0.0 default configuration is to require response level and assertion level signatures. You have possibility to configure this requirement at your SP side with @node-saml/node-saml and @node-saml/passport-saml packages' configuration options wantAuthnResponseSigned and wantAssertionsSigned. Quote from https://github.com/node-saml/node-saml/blob/v5.0.0/README.md (latest release at the time of writing this anwer):


wantAssertionsSigned: if true, add WantAssertionsSigned="true" to the metadata, to specify that the IdP should always sign the assertions. It is on by default. Note: either the response or the assertion must be signed even if both are turned off.
wantAuthnResponseSigned: if true, require that all incoming authentication response messages be signed at the top level, not just at the assertions. It is on by default. Note: either the response or the assertion must be signed even if both are turned off.


You could also configure IdP to sign both if you have opportunity to do so.
This question seems to be duplicate of: Why passport-saml can't find a signature - Invalid document signature
Consider reading through also information provided here: https://github.com/node-saml/node-saml/issues/378#issuecomment-2344755012
